# how to map and counts items occurrence in 2 Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apriori

I am new to Data science and I am still learning so excuse me if i explain my question improperly .

I have 2 dataframes, 1st DataFrame( Item) shows some grocieries product name with it is item number while the 2nd DataFrame (Transactions) shows transactions numbers containing Items Purchased .

1st DataFrame (Item)=

| Item | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Cheese |
| 201 | Milk |
| 302 | egg |

2nd DataFrame (Transations)

| Transaction |
| --- |
| 201 100 302 |
| 100 302 |
| 201 302 |

I managed to split Transactions columns and separate it by this code

`Transaction=transactions.str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1)`
the DataFrame became like

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 100 | 302 |
| 100 | 302 | None |
| 201 | 302 | None |

now i am struggling on how to map both data frames and one hot function or Get_dummies and count how many items from DataFrame ( items) were purchased/occurred in DataFrame( Transaction ).

the reason i want to do this is because I am trying to do this in order to apply Apriori function to find association rule for market basket analysis.

Hints . There dataframes are simplified , the actual data frames are 10,000 length.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

With prep of changing from multiple columns of items to single column `reshape()` it's then simple to use `value_counts()` to get counts of items in transactions.  Clearly this can also be joined/merged to products data frame.

```
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'Item': {0: 100, 1: 201, 2: 302},
 'ProductName': {0: 'Cheese', 1: 'Milk', 2: 'egg'}})
dftrans = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction': {0: '201 100 302', 1: '100 302', 2: '201 302'}})


dftrans = dftrans.Transaction.str.split(" ", expand=True)
pd.DataFrame(dftrans.values.reshape(len(dftrans)*len(dftrans.columns),1), columns=["Item"]).value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
```

|  | Item | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 302 | 3 |
| 1 | 100 | 2 |
| 2 | 201 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2.squeeze().str.split() \
                     .explode().astype(int) \
                     .rename("Item"),
             on="Item").value_counts().rename("Count").reset_index()

   Item ProductName  Count
0   302         egg      3
1   201        Milk      2
2   100      Cheese      2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the one hot encoding you may need to melt the trans dataframe first:

```
dftransnew = pd.melt(dftrans.reset_index(),value_name='Item',id_vars='index').drop(columns='variable')
dftransnew = dftransnew[pd.notnull(dftransnew.Item)] # removing nulls
```

and get_dummies and group it by transaction to get the baskets encoded:

```
dfbasket=pd.get_dummies(dftransnew, prefix="", prefix_sep="" ).groupby('index').sum()
dfbasket
```

output:

```
    100     201     302
index           
0   1       1       1
1   1       0       1
2   0       1       1
```